# 32bit ACE OleDb 16.0 Access Violation

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I am trying to use ACE OleDB 16 on an excel file. And get {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

System is Office 2016 and the Program Files (x86)\Common\Microsoft Shared\Office 16\ACEOLEDB.dll

Any input on what is going on would be very appreciated (even being called an idiot :) )

Note: The program throws an error although the code is inside a try-catch block;

Sample code:

```
string path = @"testfile.xlsx";
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source="+ path +";Extended Properties='Excel 16.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  try
    {
      OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(connString);
      OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", sheet), cnnxls);

       oda.Fill(dt);
      }
  catch (Exception e)
       {
        // error handling
        }
```

Error output:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>          at AceOleDbTest.AceOleDbTest.AceReadTest(String connString, String logPath, String sheet) in C:\Users\anokano\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\AceOleDbTest\AceOleDbTest\AceOleDbTest.cs:line 87
>          at randomtests3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\anokano\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\randomtests3\randomtests3\Program.cs:line 336
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Comment: Try reinstalling the package for 12.0 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 for 16.0 you need the Access 2016 Runtime but this can be a real pita if you have mixed 32/64 bit components.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. But do have any idea on why in such a simple use case (targeting 32 bit) it fails?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: In the end yes installing 12 again worked..